# Can't collect tcp data to vector openframworks

Tags: c++, tcpclient, openframeworks

I am trying to fill up a vector char with data from a pointer via ofxTCPClient.

The pointer tmpData is receiving the data, but I get this error if I try to push the data in to the vector.

Even if I try to fill up the vector with a char "manually" like this:
    tcpMainData.push_back('a');

do I get an error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
(lldb)
```

This is my program:

```
#include "ofApp.h"

using namespace std;

vector<char> tcpMainData;

//This is a temporary size variabel, until a function is made.
int tmpDataSize = 100;
char tmpData;


//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::setup(){

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::update(){

    //Listen on the port for tcp data if we are connected to the server
    if (!TCPClient.isConnected()) {
        state = OFFLINE;
    }else if (TCPClient.isConnected() && state != RECEIVING) {
                state = LISTENING;
    }

    //TCP package received
    if((int)TCPClient.receiveRawBytes((char *) &tcpMainData, sizeOfTcpChunk) > 1 && state == LISTENING) {

        state = RECEIVING;
    }

    //Filling up vector with tcp data
    if (state == RECEIVING) {

        for (int i = 0; i < tmpDataSize; i++) {
            TCPClient.receiveRawBytes((char *) &tmpData, sizeOfTcpChunk);

            tcpMainData.push_back(tmpData);
        }

        state = LISTENING;
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::draw(){

    if (state == OFFLINE) {
        ofDrawBitmapString("Press C to connect", 50, 100);
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::keyPressed(int key){

    if (key == 'c') {
        TCPClient.setup("127.0.0.1", TCPPort);
    }
}
```

Heres my header if it's relevant:

```
...

//TCP CONF
ofxTCPClient TCPClient;
int TCPPort = 50014;

int sizeOfTcpChunk = 4;             //Size of TCP packages (Chunks)

//Program state
enum clientState {
    OFFLINE,
    LISTENING,
    RECEIVING,
};

clientState state = LISTENING;
```

Comment: You appear to be writing a stream of bytes to an address that has only allocated one single character `tmpData`.

Answer (score 0):

You are omitting where the error occurs.
There are two things wrong here (i've put the points from your code into context here):

```
vector<char> tcpMainData;
TCPClient.receiveRawBytes((char *) &tcpMainData, sizeOfTcpChunk)
```

you cast the vector to char* wrong. It should be

```
(char *) &tcpMainData[0]
```

and I strongly doubt that you can use this for writing to `tcpMainData`. This cast is for reading from a vector only. My guess is, that you get the error message because of this.

and

```
char tmpData;
TCPClient.receiveRawBytes((char *) &tmpData, sizeOfTcpChunk);
```

As Galik mentioned, tmpData is one byte. You need something like char `tmpData[100]`

For reference, the signature of the TCPClient.receiveRawBytes function is:

```
int ofxTCPClient::receiveRawBytes(char *receiveBytes, int numBytes)
```